# For all $x$ which are real numbers, prove that $\lfloor 2x\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor x+0.5\rfloor.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> For all $x$ which are real numbers, prove that
>   $$\lfloor 2x\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor x+0.5\rfloor.$$

I know that

Let $\lfloor x\rfloor = n$

$n \leq x < n+1$

Comment: Use `$\lfloor x\rfloor$` to show $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Well your def. for floor could use a little rewording.

Comment: Divide the case $0\le \{x\} < 1/2$ and $1/2 \le \{x\} < 1$, where $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: I think this is a special case of $\lfloor nx \rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor \frac{k}{n} x \rfloor$.

Comment: I think this is a special case of $\lfloor nx \rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor x+\frac{k}{n}  \rfloor$. (first version had a mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ x = i + d $ where $ 0 \le d < 1 $

$ \lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor 2i + 2d \rfloor = 2i + \lfloor 2d \rfloor $

$ \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x + 0.5 \rfloor = 2i + \lfloor d \rfloor + \lfloor d + 0.5 \rfloor $

So we reduced the problem to just show for $ d $

Suppose $ 0 \le d < 0.5 $, then both sides are just $ 2d $

Suppose $ 0.5 \le d < 1 $, then both sides are just $ d + 1 $.

QED $ \blacksquare $

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming $\lfloor x\rfloor = n$

Let's take two cases - one - the fractional part of $x$ is less than $0.5$ 
 LHS will be $2n$ RHS will be $n+n$

case two - The fractional part of $x$ is greater than $0.5$
LHS will be $2n+1$ RHS will be $n+n+1$

Hence, proved.

Comment: You should describe what $n$ is formally, Otherwise, the proof seems to be on point.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId The question said so. Anyway, I edited.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show
$\lfloor nx \rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor  x+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor$.

Let
$m = \lfloor x \rfloor$
and
$d = x - m$,
so
$0 \le d < 1$.

Let
$j
=\lfloor nd \rfloor
$,
so
$0 \le j \le n-1
$
and
$\frac{j}{n}
\le d
< \frac{j+1}{n}
$.
If
$0 \le k \le n-j-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
m
&\le m+d+\frac{k}{n}\\
&< m+\frac{n-j}{n}+\frac{j}{n}\\
&= m+\frac{n}{n}\\
&= m+1\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor
=m
$.

If
$n-j \le k \le n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
m+d+\frac{k}{n}
&\ge m+\frac{n-j}{n}+\frac{j}{n}\\
&= m+\frac{n}{n}\\
&= m+1\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
m+d+\frac{k}{n}
&\lt m+\frac{n-j+1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\\
&= m+\frac{2n-j}{n}\\
&= m+2-\frac{j}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor
=m+1
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor x+\frac{k}{n}  \rfloor
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n}  \rfloor\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-j-1} \lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor
+\sum_{k=n-j}^{n-1} \lfloor m+d+\frac{k}{n} \rfloor\\
&= (n-j)m+j(m+1)\\
&= nm+j\\
\end{array}
$

and
$\lfloor nx \rfloor
=\lfloor n(m+d) \rfloor
=nm+\lfloor nd \rfloor
=nm+j
$.

We are done.

Answer (score -1):

$n\leq x< n+1$ , then $f(x)=n$ for all $x$

I) If $n<x< \frac{2n+1}{2}$

$f(x)+f(x+0.5)= n+n=2n=f(2x)$

since $x+0.5<\frac{2n+1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}=n+1$

II) If  $n+1>x\geq \frac{2n+1}{2}$

$f(x)+f(x+0.5)= n+n+1=2n+1=f(2x)$

Since $x+0.5\geq\frac{2n+1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}=n+1$